# Atomicity with openTempFile

Tags: file, haskell, io, temporary-files

I have the following function:

```
safeWrite :: Text -> IO ()
safeWrite c = bracket (openTempFile "/tmp" "list.tmp")
    (\(path, h) -> hClose h
      >> copyFile path dataFile
      >> removeFile path)
    (\(_, h) -> TI.hPutStr h c)
```

I was under the impression that this would safe, no copying would happen if there were errors during any moment, and the original file would still be usable. However just yesterday I ended up with an empty file, and I have no idea where to go look at it. The program had been running well for over a month without any hiccups which points so some corner case I didn't think of.

Does the method guarantee atomicity, meaning the error is somewhere else, or if not, why not? What should I do to guarantee atomicity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition of `mkTemp` is atomic *with respect to Haskell exceptions*. If there is an exception it will print a message about the failure  (leaving the file there).

- It is not atomic with respect to the Unix file system -- other programs could overwrite the same file
- It does not clean up should there be a failure.

You can do a bit more to clean up, by optionally removing the file if there is an exception, or simply using the provided  (atomic) `mkTemp`  function:

- `openTempFile`: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.3.1.0/doc/html/System-IO.html#g:22

or using the posix layer:

- http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/unix/latest/doc/html/System-Posix-Temp.html#Temp